# Ring opening of aziridinylmethyl and oxiranylmethyl radicals

Tags: organic-chemistry, radicals, heterocyclic-compounds, regioselectivity

When a radical is alpha to a three-membered ring, it is common for the ring to open via β-scission (to relieve ring strain):

[image: Ring opening of cyclopropylmethyl radical]

When the ring contains a heteroatom there are a couple of different possibilities:

[image: Epoxide/aziridine analogues]

*Ab initio* studies of these reactions<sup>1</sup> showed that for both X = O and X = NH, the C–C cleavage was thermodynamically favoured (presumably due to stabilisation of the subsequent radical by the adjacent lone pair). For X = O, the C–C cleavage was also found to be kinetically favoured, but for X = NH, the **C–N** cleavage is kinetically favoured!

This regioselectivity is also backed up by experiment<sup>2</sup> and also has potential for use in synthesis.<sup>3</sup>

[image: C–N bond cleavage, taken from ref 3]

Is there an explanation for **why the kinetically favoured products are different for X = O and NH?**

---

**References**

1. Pasto, D. J. *Ab Initio* Theoretical Studies on the Ring-Opening Modes of the Oxiranyl-, Aziridinyl-, Oxaziridinyl-, and Thiaranylmethyl Radical Systems. J. Org. Chem. 1996, 61 (1), 252–256. [DOI: 10.1021/jo9505942](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo9505942).
2. Marples, B. A.; Toon, R. C. An investigation into the β-cleavage of aziridinylcarbinyl radicals. *Tetrahedron Lett.* **1999,** *40* (26), 4873–4876. [DOI: 10.1016/S0040-4039(99)00900-4](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(99)00900-4).
3. Prévost, N.; Shipman, M. Intramolecular Radical Rearrangement Reactions of 2-Methyleneaziridines: Application to the Synthesis of Substituted Piperidines, Decahydroquinolines, and Octahydroindolizines. *Org. Lett.* **2001,** *3* (15), 2383–2385. [DOI: 10.1021/ol016194k](https://doi.org/10.1021/ol016194k).

Answer (score 2):

The 2-methyl-3-phenyloxiranylcarbinyl radical has been shown EXPERIMENTALLY to cleave the C-O bond kinetically while the C-C bond is cleaved thermodynamically. This means that, in this example, The oxygen-centered radical forms faster than the highly stable benzyl radical. The formation of the oxygen radical is necessarily reversible. See ref. 11 in your ref. 2 (Marples paper)

Ziegler, F. E.; Petersen, A. K. Allyloxy Radicals are Formed Reversibly from Oxiranylcarbinyl Radicals: A Kinetic Study, J. Org. Chem. , 1995, 60, 2666.

Comment: Fair enough, but there's the followup question: why is C–X cleaved kinetically despite forming a less stable radical? Thanks for pointing this out, nonetheless. I'll edit the question when I get a chance to.